# Why is public folder missing in Gatsby app

Tags: gatsby

I'm beginning to learn Gatsby, following a tutorial on their site. As instructed, I've downloaded a hello-world starter app just fine but in the site's tut pics, the app's directory tree has a public and content folder while mine doesn't. Could anyone tell me why? I have downloaded another starter app from another tutorial and that one does have those folders. So, I don't know, just trying to figure this out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `gatsby develop`and / or `gatsby build`? The public folder should be generated by either command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `gatsby new starter https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default`, the gatsby cli will clone the git repository into a local folder named `starter`.

However, it won't do anything else. Running `gatsby build` or `gatsby develop` will compile your site into the `public` folder (as well as adding some stuff to the `.cache` folder).

You would then have to create your own `content` folder depending on what you are trying to do.

Also, consider going through all of the [official tutorials](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/) (starting from 0) before moving on to look at any 3rd party tutorials for gatsby that you might find.

Comment: Aaaha! Yes, I started a tut on Snipcart but it was slightly vague. So, I decided to go through those official tuts on the Gatsby site to get a better understanding. I did 0 at night, then 1 the following morning and def didn't remember about `gatsby develop`. Thank you very much for taking the time to clear that up for me.

Comment: No probs. Have fun!